# eloquent - dynamic and conditional whereHas() in the query builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to avoid [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) in my query builder, specifically on adding additional method in the chain.

Example, this is initially the query builder that I have:

```
$products = $app->myShop->realProducts()
        ->where($query)
        ->skip($skip)->take($take)
        ->orderBy($sortKey, $sortOrder)
        ->get();
```

Then if user used some filter, I needed to append a method (specifically a `whereHas()`) to the query builder

```
    $products = $app->myShop->realProducts()
        ->where($query)
        ->whereHas('colour', function ($q) use ($find) {
            $q->where('colour_slug', $find);
        })
        ->skip($skip)->take($take)
        ->orderBy($sortKey, $sortOrder)
        ->get();
```

I find it "ugly" that to achieve this result, I have to keep repeating those builder query:

```
if ($user_filtered_this_page == TRUE) {

    $products = $app->myShop->realProducts()->where($query)
        ->whereHas('colour', function ($q) use ($find) {
            $q->where('colour_slug', $find);
        })
        ->skip($skip)->take($take)
        ->orderBy($sortKey, $sortOrder)
        ->get();

} else {

    $products = $app->myShop->realProducts()->where($query)
        ->skip($skip)->take($take)
        ->orderBy($sortKey, $sortOrder)
        ->get();
}
```

Is there a more clever or elegant way to dynamically and conditionally append the `whereHas()` method to the chain?

Hope somebody can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The query doesn't get executed until you call `->get()` so you can quite simply build your query, conditionally add your `->whereHas()` and then execute it:

```
$query= $app->myShop->realProducts()
    ->where($query)
    ->skip($skip)->take($take)
    ->orderBy($sortKey, $sortOrder);

if (...) {
    $query->whereHas(...);
}

$products = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be done using [Query Builder Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
    $products = $app->myShop->realProducts()
        ->where($query)
        ->when($user_filtered_this_page, function($query) use($find){
            $query->whereHas('colour', function ($q) use ($find) {
                $q->where('colour_slug', $find);
            })
        })
        ->skip($skip)->take($take)
        ->orderBy($sortKey, $sortOrder)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this:

```
$products = $app->myShop->realProducts()->where($query)
            ->whereHas('colour', function ($q) use ($find) {
                if ($user_filtered_this_page) {
                $q->where('colour_slug', $find);
            }
            })
            ->skip($skip)->take($take)
            ->orderBy($sortKey, $sortOrder)
            ->get();
```

Hope it help you ;)

Comment: i think this would not give the desired result, because it would skip `realProducts()` without the `colour` relation.